# wpf - Duplicate Animation on Same Control

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have been looking for a way in order to animate an object more than once with the same animation. I have a textblock that I want to move down the y-axis by a certain amount and I want it to hold there. Later I want to move the textblock further down the y-axis with the same animation. So far whenever I try this, all it does it revert the textblock to its original position and then animate it. I've looked around and haven't really seen any questions that pertain to mine, so I figured I would ask my own. Here is the method that plays the animation.

```
private void Anim_TextBlocks()
    {
        foreach (TextBlock aBlock in theTextBlocks)
        {       
            var tg = new TransformGroup();
            var translation = new TranslateTransform(30, 0);
            var translationName = "t" + translation.GetHashCode();
            RegisterName(translationName, translation);
            tg.Children.Add(translation);
            aBlock.RenderTransform = tg;
            var anim = new DoubleAnimation();
            anim.By = 100;
            anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
            anim.EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

            var story = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(story, translationName);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(story, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.YProperty));
            var storyboardName = "s" + story.GetHashCode();
            Resources.Add(storyboardName, story);
            story.Children.Add(anim);

            story.Completed += delegate
            {
                if (queue.Count != 0)
                    Create_TextBlock(this, null);
                else
                    button1.Content = "off";
            };
            this.BeginStoryboard(story, HandoffBehavior.Compose, true);
            button1.Content = "on";
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: DispatcherTimer may help to animate something N times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that recreating the TranslateTransform every time was making my textblocks start from the original position. After making the necessary changes, my code now works and looks like this:

```
foreach (TextBlock aBlock in theTextBlocks)
  {
    // Check for existing TranslateTransform
    var translation = aBlock.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    if (translation == null)
    {
      aBlock.RenderTransform  = new TranslateTransform(30, 0);
    }
    translation = aBlock.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
    var anim = new DoubleAnimation();
    anim.By = 100;
    anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    anim.EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

     anim.Completed += delegate
    {
      if (queue.Count != 0)
        Create_TextBlock(this, null);
      else
        button1.Content = "off";
    };
     translation.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
     button1.Content = "on";
  }
```